# Responsive site works in FF responsive design view but not when i resize the browser

Tags: html, css, firefox, less

As described, it's working in the responsive design view in FF but not when I resize my browser by dragging the edges. Also, I realized that it works in android but not on iPhone, if that tells you anything.

And yes, I've added the meta viewport tag. I can't really find anything on google that's helping me solve this.

If you need any information about my code structure, please ask. I have no idea what to give you to help assess.

The site is using HTML, LESS and jQuery. I linked the markup to the css file because it's not working at all when I link it to mobile.less.

```
@media (min-width: 0px)
and (max-width: 640px)
and (orientation: portrait)
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles/main.less"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 640px)" href="styles/mobile.css"/>
```

Comment: Try to remove max-device width in your second css call... leave just max-width. However, even if this will work when you test in Responsive Design View, on different resolutions, it is not enough to cover all cases when user resize browser window....

Comment: That worked for the browser. I don't have an iphone so i can't test it now. But thank you!

Comment: Show Your viewport tag